# Column has Multiple Values Used as Identifiers for Next Column

Tags: mysql

MySQL column has multiple values used as identifiers for the next column. Table Structure:

```
id (key),  occurrence_id,  name,  value
```

The `name` column values then correspond to the `values` column. How can I display this information in one view?

Currently, it looks like this:

```
occurrence_id name           value
1576          Attempts       1
1576          ClientIP       "94.xxx.xxx.xxx"
1576          UserAgent      ""
1576          CurrentUserID  0<
```

I want to make a view that will look like this:

```
occurrence_id  Attempts  Client IP         CurrentUserID
1576           1         "94.xxx.xxx.xxx"  0
2009           30        "68.111.xxx.xxx"  0
```

Answer (score 0):

One method is using conditional aggregation:

```
select occurrence_id,
       max(case when name = 'Attempts' then value end) as Attempts,
       max(case when name = 'ClientIP' then value end) as ClientIP,
       max(case when name = 'UserAgent' then value end) as UserAgent,
       max(case when name = 'CurrentUserID' then value end) as CurrentUserID
from table t
group by occurrence_id;
```

Comment: That works great .... but only returns one result.

When I try add it fails:  

**WHERE name = 'Attempts' AND `value` > '0'** 



And, thank you for posting that fast reply.